# Upnpx LastChangeParser

Tags: ios, xcode, upnp, sonos

i´m testing upnpx Library to control a sonos multi room audio system... working quit well.
I have just one main problem with events.
If i get an volume change event from sonos renderer, like this

```
<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/"><InstanceID val="0"><Volume channel="Master" val="66"/><Volume channel="LF" val="100"/><Volume channel="RF" val="100"/></InstanceID></Event>
```

i´m getting not the hole event and wrong values in
-(void)UPnPEvent:(BasicUPnPService*)sender events:(NSDictionary*)events{

```
InstanceID = 100; Volume = 100;
```

it should be ...

```
InstanceID = 0; Volume = 66;
```

I would be very happy if someone could advise me into the right direction!

Best regards
FTZ

```
upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: propertyset

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: property

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: LastChange

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didEndElement: LastChange, obj: <Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/"><InstanceID val="0"><Volume channel="Master" val="52"/><Volume channel="LF" val="100"/><Volume channel="RF" val="100"/></InstanceID></Event>

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] LastChange - element:LastChange, value:<Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/"><InstanceID val="0"><Volume channel="Master" val="52"/><Volume channel="LF" val="100"/><Volume channel="RF" val="100"/></InstanceID></Event>

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: Event

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: InstanceID

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: Volume

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] LastChangeParser.h void propertyName name:Volume value:52

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: Volume

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] LastChangeParser.h void propertyName name:Volume value:100

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] BasicParser.h didStartElement: Volume

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] LastChangeParser.h void propertyName name:Volume value:100

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] LastChangeParser.h void propertyName name:InstanceID value:100

upnpxdemo[66489:1310b] Event Digctionary: {
    InstanceID = 100;
    Volume = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is correct. I downloaded upnpx source but could not readily understand the `BasicParser` and `UPnPEventParser` logic - i worked in Objective-C only for so long. I wonder how is upnpx accounting for the fact that you can have multiple values for the same key, different only by `channel` attribute. It's an exception in the naming convention for `LastChange` event, the keys are generally unique. The last `Volume` present in the event is 100, so upnpx is perhaps replacing value for `Volume` key all the time.

It does not explain the InstanceID misnumbering though. Are you sure you got that one right? Can you post a full dump of the `events` NSDictionary?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i added the log of the event... thx FTZ

Comment: So i was right about the `Volume`. The log refers to it 3 times without ever mentioning the `channel` property, which means that the 3 values are stored in the same NSDictionary key (overwriting the previous value). The incorrect `InstanceID` seems to be somehow connected to this overwriting, as it gets the same value. I don't have time to study the upnpx code. But it's definitely a bug in there and a Defect should be filled at upnpx site.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your evaluation of the problem!! I will fill an issue at upnpx group.

Comment: Thanking on Stack Overflow = upvoting and/or accepting the answer :)